# Change and Keyup Event Handler in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, cakephp

I'm using JQuery, CakePHP, and Mysql in my application.
I'm having a code like below in which instructions are a Textbox that when I type it will be shown in the Display panel.

```
$(".TextFieldSettings #instructions").keyup(function (){
  instr=$(".TextFieldSettings #instructions").val();
  $("#displayPanel .fieldInstructions"+counter).html(instr).show();
});//Text field instructions keyup
```

This Code Works well.

Edit:
  If I change the value in the Textbox instructions, the keyup value must be shown in the Display Panel. Mean while I need the final changed value in the instr to insert into the database.
How can I do so?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? I'm having a hard time following...

Comment: I agree with Paolo.  Are you asking how to insert the data into the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can delay your operation :

```
$(".TextFieldSettings #instructions").keyup(function (){
  setTimeout(function () {
    var instr=$(".TextFieldSettings #instructions").val();
    $("#displayPanel .fieldInstructions"+counter).html(instr).show();
  }, 1);
});//Text field instructions keyup
```

That way, when the function is executed, the input value has been updated with the keypress.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much content your instructions is holding/how frequently keypressing, i think updating the database every keyup is a bit overkill. Maybe update the database every 5 seconds or something? with each keypress triggering/resetting a setTimeout function.

Also, you can replace your call to pull out the text value with just $(this);

```
$(".TextFieldSettings #instructions").keyup(function (){
    var instr = $(this).val();
    $("#displayPanel .fieldInstructions"+counter).html(instr).show();

    // Update database
    $.ajax({ 
              method: 'POST', 
              url: 'path/to/a/script_file/executing_the_sql.ext',
              data: { 'str': escape(instr.replace(/\n/g,'<br />')) },
              success: function(){},
              error: function(e){ alert(e.responseText); }
    });

});//Text field instructions keyup
```